# Google Play Console - Crashes and ANR older than 60 days

Tags: android, google-play-console

My app on google play was very buggy and crashes a lot. I decided to turn it off until i have time to fix it because it started to gain bad opinions.
In App statistics i can see how many crashes and ANRs there was that time but i can't see issues in Android Vitals > Crashes and ANRs older than 60 days.
Is there any way to see crashes and anrs older than 60 days?

Comment: No. Play deletes the data older than 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting current crash reports, then you need to check whether you have implemented the analytics before i.e. the time slot you are looking for.

In console there is crash reports as per by the version and the time frame. Perhaps a change in the console caused this issue.

Further, check the updated Google policies. Delete the data even from your Google Drive in case you have data for longer than the specific time period decided by Google.